# Why can't I run krumo() on a node page?

Tags: 7, debugging

I called `krumo()` inside `hook_node_load()`.

```
function mymodule1_node_load($nodes, $types) {
    krumo($nodes);
}
```

It works on my front page, but not on a node page. I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function krumo() in C:\wamp\vhosts\mydrupal72\sites\all\modules\my_customs\mymodule1\mymodule1.module on line 126

Why can't I run `krumo()` on a node page?

Comment: because krumo() is not defined.

Comment: Huh?? How is it not defined? `Devel` module is installed and enabled. Why does it work on front page but not a node page?

Comment: Try to use [dsm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dsm/7.x-1.x) or [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x) instead

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using `module_load_include()`. Manually making sure it's loaded